# Definition of a bounded, nonempty subset of real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

When one refers to a "bounded, nonempty subset of real numbers" does it have to be a continuous subset or can it be a set of discrete numbers (e.g. $S = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$)?

Thank you.

Comment: It does not have to be continuous. It can be just one number, or any finite subset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bounded set is one which could be contained in an interval $[a,b]$

It could be finite or infinite, continuous or discrete.

For example the set $\{1,1/2,1/3,...\}$ is a nonempty bounded set because it is contained in $[0,1]$

The interval $(0,1)$ is bounded because it is contained in $[0,1]$

The set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is bounded because it is contained in $[1,5]$

Answer (score 3):

Recall that we can say $S \subseteq \Bbb R$ is "bounded" if there exists $m,M \in \Bbb R$ such that, for all $s \in S$, $m \le s \le M$. We also say $S$ is "nonempty" if ... well, it contains elements, that's simple enough.

---

Edit: a more intuitive idea of this principle is, as given by Mohammad Riazi-Kermani in their answer, is that $S$ is a nonempty subset of some finite interval. In my definition above, that interval is $[m,M]$.

---

Neither of these tenets require finiteness or connectedness. For example, $S = \{1\}$ is bounded, with $m=M=1$, and is obviously non-empty. The Cantor set is bounded and nonempty with $m=0,M=1$, but is totally disconnected. Your example set of $S=\{0,1,2,3\}$ is bounded and nonempty with $m=0,M=3$.

But we can also have continuous/connected examples as well. For instance, $S=(-2,2)$ is bounded and nonempty with $m=-2,M=2$. Or perhaps we take $S = (1,3) \cup (4,6)$, which is nonempty and bounded with $m=1,M=6$.

Answer (score 2):

If I wanted a "continuous" subset, I would say "interval".

"$S = \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$"

Hmm...

- Bounded?  Let's see if it's bounded by $100$.  $|0| \leq 100$.  $|1| \leq 100$.  $|2| \leq 100$.  $|3| \leq 100$.  Yes, it's bounded.
- Nonempty?  $1 \in S$, so $S$ is nonempty.
- Subset?  $0 \in \Bbb{R}$, $1 \in \Bbb{R}$, $2 \in \Bbb{R}$, and $3 \in \Bbb{R}$, so $S \subset \Bbb{R}$.

Nonemptiness required a "choice", but that choice is trivial.  The only one that involved a nontrivial "choice" was boundedness.  Of course if you are picking a set, you probably know or can can probably find a (tight) bound.  If the set is defined in a sufficiently complicated manner, finding a bound may require some work/creativity and such a set may be unbounded.  (Consider the set of [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).  Looking at the small members, they might *seem* to be bounded.  They aren't.)

Comment: Does the word “continuous” apply to sets? Does it mean the same thing as “connected”?

Comment: No.  Continuous is a word usually applied to functions (and the usage requires a topology or metric).  You might use "[contiguous](https://simple.wiktionary.org/wiki/contiguous)", but no one would recognize the usage so it would need to be defined.

Comment: Then why did you say, “If I wanted a continuous subset...”?

Comment: @Joe : Because OP has introduced a word and I am using it in the same sense as the OP.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to tell the OP that he is using the word incorrectly? I’m not trying to be picky, but I’d hate the OP, or future readers of your answer, to think that the word continuous applies to sets.

Comment: @Joe : I believe I did -- in exactly the helpful, non-pedantic way my wrong usage of words was explained to me when I learned a foreign language.

Answer (score 0):

Non empty is self explanatory.
Bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ simply means you can contain your set within an interval $(-m,m)$, where every single element of your set has to be less than or equal to $m.$
Your set does not need to be continuous or an interval.

For example, the set $A= \{1,2,4,7\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is bounded by $8$. It is also bounded by $9$ and even $7$, but no number smaller than $7$ in this case.